# Extend jQuery UI Dialog open function

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, extend

Is it possible to extend the "open" callback function for the jQuery UI dialog? For example, I am extending my modalDialog box with another called confirmDialog.  When opening the modalDialog dialog, I am running a couple of functions that I want to carry over to the confirmDialog but also add another function with it.  Here is the code:

```
// Default settings for the modal dialog
moDefaults : {
    autoOpen: 'false',
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {},
    title: 'Title',
    width: 'auto',
    open: function(getDataOnOpen){
        // Add open class
        jQuery(this).addClass('open_dialog');

        // Add classes to action button
        var buttonPane = jQuery(this).next();
        jQuery(buttonPane).find('button:first').addClass('accept').addClass('action');

        // Hide the default dialog close button
        jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();

        // IE hack
        jQuery(this).css('overflow','hidden');

        // Ajax call to make on open
        getDataOnOpen;
    },
    close: function(){
        // Remove open class
        jQuery('.ui-dialog').removeClass('open_dialog');
    }
},

modalDialog : function(options, dialogId){

    if(options){
        jQuery.extend(true, mw.moDefaults, options);
    }

    jQuery(dialogId).dialog(mw.moDefaults);
},

confirmDialog : function(options){

    var defaults = {
        dialogClass:'confirm_dialog',
        minWidth: 255,
        modal: true
    };

    var settings = $.extend(mw.moDefaults, defaults, options);

    $.extend(mw.modalDialog(settings,'#conf_dialog'));
}
```

Thanks in advance SO!!

Comment: Did you try to override JQueryUI Dialog class using prototype parameter?